# Users can not login into wordpress website

Tags: login

I have a wordpress site set up. I'm Using JANNAH theme from Themeforest by Tielabs. For this project I need forums and user profiles (And perhaps user groups in future) so I'm using buddypress and bbpress as well. I have set up the theme and added a forums page to it.

The website is live and working well except that the users can not seem to login. I can access admin dashboard using the administrator account but even admin account doesnt get me logged into the website ( I keep getting "You must be logged in to post a new topic" on forums page). The login page gets through without any error but login doesnt seem to work.

You can check it out here 
www.shutterclan.com

I couldnt find solution to this problem on internet. I remember reading somewhere that buddypress login system can sometimes conflict with wordpress login mechanism. Could it be that or something elese ??

I can provide .htaccess, apache settings or php settings whichever is required. I have intermediate level of knowledge about wordpress except for the coding part as I am not a coder.

I would really appreciate any help given :)

Abdul

Comment: I am logged in with the user test - I have created a user and it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to ‘Forum Rules’ and change the option "open to new topics and replies"

Comment: Hi Nuno. Do you mean the forum named " Forum Rules " ? Or is it some settings option ?  
P..S once logged in, can you create a new topic in any of the forums ?
Thanks for the quick help though. :) I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: are you following this tutorial https://codex.bbpress.org/step-by-step-guide-to-setting-up-a-bbpress-forum ?

Comment: have a look on this "Forum visibility:" section :)

Comment: or if you prefer not reading here is a video in how to setup bbpress - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsU18dWFcD8